# Redefining a set of transformations as a single linear transformation using tensor product?

Tags: linear-transformations, tensor-products

I learned today that a multilinear map $A \times A \rightarrow B$ can be re-defined as a single linear map $A \otimes  A \rightarrow B$, where $\otimes$ is the tensor product.

I have a set of transformations in an iterative algorithm, and I would like to determine if they collectively count as a multilinear map, in order to "reduce" the multiple transformations to one linear map. Here are the set of transformations I want to represent as one transformation:

$\mathbf{y}^{t}_d = \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_d \odot (W \cdot \left(\mathbf{y}^{t}_{d-1} \oslash (W^{\text{T}} \cdot \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_d)\right) + \left( (V \cdot \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_{d+1}) \oslash \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_d\right))$

This can be rewritten as a function $\mathbf{y}^{t}_d = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}^{t-1}_d, \mathbf{y}^{t}_{d-1}, \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_{d+1}, W, W^{\text{T}}, V)$. This function involves three linear transformations, $W, W^\text{T}, V$. My goal is to determine whether I can use a "tensor product trick" to rewrite $\mathbf{f}$ as a function of a single linear transformation, $U$. That is, I want to find $U$ such that:

$\mathbf{y}^{t}_d = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}^{t-1}_d, \mathbf{y}^{t}_{d-1}, \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_{d+1}, W, W^{\text{T}}, V) = \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{y}^{t-1}_d, \mathbf{y}^{t}_{d-1}, \mathbf{y}^{t-1}_{d+1}, U)$

Is this possible? Am I even on the right track with this sort of idea?

EDIT: $\odot$ and $\oslash$ represent element-wise multiplication and division respectively. $\mathbf{y}^{t}_{d-1}, \mathbf{y}^{t}_{d}, \mathbf{y}^{t}_{d+1}$ are vectors in three different vector spaces. $t$ represents the iteration during which the vector was computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is "no", it is not multi-linear for a couple reasons.

**(1)** If you look at the last term in your equation, the vector $V \cdot y^{t-1}_{d+1}$ is being both multiplied *and* divided (component-wise) by $y^{t-1}_d$. The multiplication and division cancel, so that term actually does not depend at all on $y^{t-1}_d$. Thus it is not multilinear.

For a simpler example, think of $f(x,y) = xy + x$. Then$f(x,y_1+y_2) = xy_1 + xy_2 + x$, but on the other hand, $f(x,y_1)+f(x,y_2) = xy_1+xy_2 + 2x$, which is different. They are not the same because the second term does not depend on $y$. This is what is happening in your function.

**(2)** Also, the component-wise division is not a linear operation, so you shouldn't expect your function to be multi-linear because of that. Consider just $v,w \in \Bbb{R}^2$ given by $v = \binom{x}{y}$ and $w = \binom{a}{b}$. Then
$$ v \oslash w = \begin{pmatrix} x/a \\ y/b \end{pmatrix} $$
It is linear in $v$, but not in $w$:
$$ v \oslash (w_1+w_2) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{a_1+a_2} \\ \frac{y}{b_1+b_2} \end{pmatrix} $$
This is definitely not the same as $v \oslash w_1 + v \oslash w_2$.